# How to use Laravel's hasManyThrough on self-referenced tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-relations

I have the User and Regional models, which I want to get some regionals from the user type of supervisor. So here is how I define the relationship.

```
public function regional()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Regional::class);
}

/**
 * Get all user that belongs to this supervisor
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function amOfSupervisor()
{
    return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'supervisor_id');
}
```

I can get the user's regional by `$user->regional`, but how to get all regional based on the user that belongs to this user? I've tried `hasManyThrough()` but always an error. What's wrong, or what should I do?

```
public function RegionalSV()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Regional::class, 
        User::class,'supervisor_id', 'regional_id');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hasManyThrough uses when  Project has Environment and Environment has departement
we can use

```
hasManyThrough( departement::class,Environment::class,'project_id','Environment_id','id','id')
```

so you have User has many users and each user belongs to regional

you can do

```
 Regional::whereExists(function($query){
$query->selectRaw('1')->from('users')->whereColumn('users.regional_id','regionals.id')
->where('users.supervisor_id',$this->id);
})->get()
```

or

```
Regional::join(self::class,'users.regional_id','=','regionals.id')
->where('users.supervisor_id',$this->id)->get();
```

Comment: The firs example is working but the second one is not. self::class referenced to the controller, I think even the first one is working but the second one more readable, but not working

Comment: in User model  (self::class)